# Showing FlatListView in Modal, working in scrollview

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to show a list in the Modal Component. I am able to get the list working in the scrollview but when trying to add it to the Modal, nothing renders. The list extends FlatListView. The list that renders the list is the same in the Modal and the Scrollview.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <Modal animationType={"slide"} transparent={false}
    visible={this.state.modalVisible}
    <View style={styles.modal}>
      <AsanaListview itemList={this.state.arrayHolder} />
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {
        this.toggleModal(!this.state.modalVisible)
      }}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Close Modal</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
  </Modal>

  <ScrollView style={styles.container} contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}>
    <View style={styles.helpContainer}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._handleAddExercisePress} style={styles.addExercises}>
        <Text style={styles.helpLinkText}>Add Exercise</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    <AsanaListview itemList={this.state.arrayHolder} />
  </ScrollView>
</View>
```

Comment: Are you setting the scrollview size?

Comment: I am not, but I added a flatlist in the Modal and it worked. Just the composite version doesn't seem to work

Comment: You need to set the scrollview size. Or set the modal size and set flex:1 to the scrollview.